# Paperclip + Active_admin + Rails 3.0.10 multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

I have a crud with paperclip and multiple images' i implement active_admin and the product update fine, but, i can't not upload or edit the multiple images, the form i have is this:

```
form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :created_at, :label => "Publish Product at"
    f.input :category
  end

  f.inputs "Images" do
    f.has_many :assets do |p|
      p.input :asset, :as => :file, :input_html => { :multiple => true }, :label => "Image", :hint => p.object.asset.nil? ? p.template.content_tag(:span, "No Image Yet") : p.template.image_tag(p.object.asset.url(:thumb))
      p.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label=>'Remove'
    end
  end

  f.inputs "Content" do
    f.input :description
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

and the...

```
f.inputs "Images" do
    f.has_many :assets do |p|
      p.input :asset, :as => :file, :input_html => { :multiple => true }, :label => "Image", :hint => p.object.asset.nil? ? p.template.content_tag(:span, "No Image Yet") : p.template.image_tag(p.object.asset.url(:thumb))
      p.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label=>'Remove'
    end
  end
```

I want to upload images, but when i create a new asset this have a missing image default and not attach the correct image, i think because the path from the images is not correct to upload. My asset model is:

```
 class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :large => "340x330", :medium => "140x80>", :thumb => "70x70>" },
     :url => "/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",  
     :path => ":rails_root/public/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
 end
```

how i can modify my assets form to work like i want? Thank you!

Comment: you should move your solution to an answer and select your own answer.  this will remove your question from the unanswered questions list and also give you another badge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Solution**

Hi, here is the solution, the key are how work the nested attributes in formtastic...

```
 form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
   f.inputs "Product information" do
     f.input :name
     f.input :description
   end

   f.inputs "Product images" do
     f.has_many :assets do |p|
       p.input :asset, :as => :file, :label => "Image",:hint => p.object.asset.nil? ? p.template.content_tag(:span, "No Image Yet") : p.template.image_tag(p.object.asset.url(:thumb))
       p.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove image'
     end 
   end

   f.inputs "Product details" do
     f.input :category, :label => "Category", :hint => "Select one category"
     f.input :height
     f.input :width
     f.input :depth
     f.input :color, :label => "Color", :hint => "Select one color"
     f.input :sku, :label => "SKU"
     f.input :price
   end
   f.buttons
 end
```

Comment: hi, i have tried this but get "undefined method `has_many' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081836/multiple-image-upload-in-active-admin-ror I am also try but not working